# typeScript void error when sestate used in click handle

Tags: reactjs, typescript

when i want use sestate (setCardItem) throw this error :
Argument of type '(prev: cartItemType[]) => cartItemType[] | void[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<cartItemType[]>'.
[all of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aZEE.jpg)

```
type cartItemType = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
  category: string;
  image: string;
  amount: number;
};
    const [cardItem, setCardItem] = useState<cartItemType[] >([]);
    const handleClickAddToCard = (clickedItem: cartItemType) => {
        setCardItem(prev => {
          // 1. is the item already added in the card?
          const isItemInCard = prev.find((item) => item.id === clickedItem.id);
          if (isItemInCard) {
            return prev.map((item) => {
              item.id === clickedItem.id
              ? { ...item, amount: item.amount + 1 }
              : item;
            });
          }
          // 2. first time item added in card
          return [...prev, { ...clickedItem, amount: 1 }];
        });
        
      };
```

this is all of the code and declared state cardItem

[code error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdlgb.png)
when setCardItem (prev => {}) type script erorr says: void dos not assainable to prev type

Comment: Could you attach your code directly in the post? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for details how to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at your `map` invocation. There is no `return` statement, so by design it returns `void`. You probably wanted to use parentheses instead of braces. If you want to stay with braces use following code:

```
if (isItemInCard) {
    return prev.map((item) => {
        return item.id === clickedItem.id ?
            { ...item, amount: item.amount + 1 } :
            item;
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, very helpful and solve my problem